# "Write a program that counts from 0 to 10 and then back down, with a seconds pause between each number. You must use loops."

Tags: python

I have done this:

```
import time

for x in range(0, 11, 1):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)
```

But it just counts up and not back down. How could I fix it?

Comment: You should investigate the parameters of the `range()` function.

Comment: In general i would encourage you to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to get the best feedback

Answer (score 1):

It counts just up because you said it to him to count up.

the third parameter is the magnitude of the step as explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp). You must use two loops to accomplish this.

```
import time

for x in range(0, 11):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)

time.sleep(1)
for x in range(9, -1, -1):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)
```

Comment: Oh yes I see now I was being stupid. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by concatenating to lists as

```
import time

for x in list(range(11)) +list(range(10, -1, -1)):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```